# Unix. Concatenate files with similar name pattern but different numbering following order

Tags: unix, concatenation

In a directory, I have thousands of files. Some of them have names like `geno_chr1_all.txt`, `geno_chr2_all.txt`, `geno_chr3_all.txt`, etc.

```
geno_chr1_all.txt

1 2 3 4
2 4 5 6

geno_chr2_all.txt

2 5 6 7 
1 1 2 2 

geno_chr3_all.txt

8 8 8 8 
0 9 0 9
```

I would like to concatenate (by columns) the contents of these files following the order given by `1,2,3,...` using Unix commands. I would then like to create a single file `output_file.txt` with these contents:

```
output_file.txt

1 2 3 4
2 4 5 6
2 5 6 7 
1 1 2 2 
8 8 8 8 
0 9 0 9
```

Any suggestion would be welcomed !

Comment: `cat file1 file2 file3 > outputfile`  ?

Comment: Thank you @iamauser, but I need the output file to be ordered according to the input files numbering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "1  1  1" > geno_chr1_all.txt
$ echo "2  2  2" > geno_chr2_all.txt
$ echo "3  3  3" > geno_chr3_all.txt
$ echo "10 10 10" > geno_chr10_all.txt
```

Use `?` to represent the digits in each file names,

```
$ cat geno_chr?_all.txt geno_chr??_all.txt > outputfile.txt
$ cat outputfile.txt
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
10 10 10
```

`?` represents single character whereas `??` represents two characters and so on... In this case, it represents the ordering digits. In case of a thousand file, one could do:

```
$ cat geno_chr?_all.txt geno_chr??_all.txt geno_chr???_all.txt geno_chr????_all.txt > outputfile.txt
```

You can also use shell expansion `{..}` to represent all relevant files,

```
$ cat geno_chr{?,??,???,????}_all.txt
```